# An Uint8Array is being cast into a String when Placed in a For Loop in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am looping over an Array of Uint8Array in TypeScript, but I get an error in Visual Studio that each specific Uint8Array is actually a string and it fails the typeCheck. I'm not sure why this is happening.

```
function failState (arrayOfUint8Array: Array<Uint8Array>){

    for (const specificUint8Array in arrayOfUint8Array){

         functionRequiringUint8Array(specificUint8Array)

        //specificUint8Array is a String and can't be used in function
        

    }
}
```

Comment: `in` iterates over the enumerable properties of `arrayOfUint8Array`. You probably meant to use `of` instead.

Comment: Yeah that fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use a `for-of` instead of a `for-in` loop.

The main difference between a [for-in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop and a [for-of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop is that a `for-in` loop iterates of the own enumerable properties of the object that's passed in.

In case of an array it will return numbers from `0` to `Array.length - 1` - the indices of the array.

```
const arr: string[] = ["Mike", "Pete", "Jack"];
for(const key in arr){
  console.log(key); // prints "0", "1", "2".
}
```

A `for-of` loop on the other hand iterates over iterable objects or user-defined iterables.

```
const arr: string[] = ["Mike", "Pete", "Jack"];
for(const name of arr){
  console.log(name); // prints "Mike", "Pete", "Jack".
}
```